# Tkinter entry boxes

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I need to count from a starting input value to an ending value using tkinter entry boxes but the 2 output files are blank except for brackets and I know that the csv outputs work it's just getting the user input that is the issue. Thanks for any help.

There is the current code.

```
import csv
from tkinter import *

# Variables/Arrays
oddArray = []
evenArray = []


def main():
    for i in range(oute1, oute2):
        x = i
        # Odds
        if(x % 2 == 1):
            oddArray.append(x)
        # Evens
        elif(x % 2 == 0):
            evenArray.append(x)

    with open("odd_labels", "w") as outputFile1:
        writer1 = csv.writer(outputFile1)
        writer1.writerow([oddArray])

    with open("even_labels", "w") as outputFile2:
        writer2 = csv.writer(outputFile2)
        writer2.writerow([evenArray])


# gui framework
myGui = Tk()
# myGui.geometry('225x50')
# myGui.title("Label Creator")

Label(myGui, text="Starting value: ").grid(row=0)
Label(myGui, text="Ending value: ").grid(row=1)

a = IntVar()
b = IntVar()

e1 = Entry(myGui, textvariable=a).grid(row=0, column=1)
e2 = Entry(myGui, textvariable=b).grid(row=1, column=1)

oute1 = a.get()
oute2 = b.get()

Button(myGui, text="Start", command=main).grid(row=3)

myGui.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is how you create your entry fields.

When you use the grid manager at the end of a widget creation then you are unable to use `.get()` on it because the grid manager is returning `None`. To avoid this you need to make sure you create your widget first then define where it goes on a separate line.

Change:

```
e1 = Entry(myGui, textvariable=a).grid(row=0, column=1)
e2 = Entry(myGui, textvariable=b).grid(row=1, column=1)
```

to:

```
e1 = Entry(myGui, textvariable=a)
e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
e2 = Entry(myGui, textvariable=b)
e2.grid(row=1, column=1)
```

I notived your `oute1` and `oute2` are both only created on the start of the program. You need to move them into a function and it should work fine in your `main` function.

Try this:

```
import csv
from tkinter import *


myGui = Tk()

oddArray = []
evenArray = []

Label(myGui, text="Starting value: ").grid(row=0)
Label(myGui, text="Ending value: ").grid(row=1)

a = IntVar()
b = IntVar()

e1 = Entry(myGui, textvariable=a)
e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
e2 = Entry(myGui, textvariable=b)
e2.grid(row=1, column=1)

def main():
    oute1 = a.get()
    oute2 = b.get()
    for i in range(oute1, oute2):
        x = i
        # Odds
        if(x % 2 == 1):
            oddArray.append(x)
        # Evens
        elif(x % 2 == 0):
            evenArray.append(x)

    with open("odd_labels", "w") as outputFile1:
        writer1 = csv.writer(outputFile1)
        writer1.writerow([oddArray])

    with open("even_labels", "w") as outputFile2:
        writer2 = csv.writer(outputFile2)
        writer2.writerow([evenArray])


Button(myGui, text="Start", command=main).grid(row=3)

myGui.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but that didn't fix it and the files are both still returning only brackets.

Comment: Thats because your oute1 and oute2 are created at the start of your program and never change. You need to move them into a function that is called on an event like a button click or something.

Comment: @JoeAckerson: I updated my answer with some more info.

Comment: Thank you everything is working now I just started using tkinter today so I appreciate the help.

Comment: There is a good amount to learn about tkinter. It is a very useful library.